# How to display multiple forms on the same page and store it on the database in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

This is my model class

```
class Marking(models.Model):
    criteria = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    marks = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(AssignAssignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is form class

```
class MarkingCriteria(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Marking
      fields = ('criteria', 'marks', 'assignment')`
```

My requirement is how to create multiple marking criteria for marking on a page. a lecturer can add as many as marking criteria on the same page and submit.

any idea how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Formsets to work with multiple forms on the same page.

```
>>> from django.forms import formset_factory
>>> MarkingCriteriaFormSet = formset_factory(MarkingCriteria)
```

Read complete documentation and examples here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/

You will need to add some javascript as well to enable adding new forms dynamically (just like django-admin)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224432/urgent-how-to-generate-formset-with-the-details-of-information-store-in-databa  any idea how to do this ?